# how to dynamically generate output in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I'm creating an AKS cluster, with node subnet id input as a parameter, before AKS cluster is created, the subnet doesn't have a routetable association, but the routetable will be created as part of AKS cluster creation, and link to the subnet, because I'm using Kubenet.

so I have output as this

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "aks_subnet" {
  name                 = var.aks_subnet.name
  resource_group_name  = var.aks_subnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.aks_subnet.virtual_network_name
}

output "routetable_id" {
  description = "Returns the routetable id."
  value       = data.azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.route_table_id
}
```

In another file, I'm trying to reference this routetable ID and link the subnet of the application gateway

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "apgwsubnet" {
  subnet_id      = module.application_gateway.apgw_subnet_id
  route_table_id = module.aks.routetable_id
  depends_on = [ module.aks]
}
```

I thought by using a depends_on, it will create the AKS cluster, and then routetable will be referenced, However, I'm getting error

```
Error: Can not parse "route_table_id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "": empty url
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "in another file" you mean in another Terraform module?

Comment: The data resource is looked up during the Terraform `plan` phase, before your `apply` happens. So the value was looked up and was found to be empty before you applied anything, and it was never looked up again after any resources were created. Unfortunately this is a pain point when working with resources that implicitly create other resources behind the scenes out of Terraform's control. I don't know much about Azure, but could you add an empty route table to the subnet via Terraform instead of relying on AKS to add it?

Comment: [Here](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources#data-resource-dependencies) they say data resources can also have `depends_on`. I suspect that inside the module `data.azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet` should be declared to depend on `resource.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.xxx`. But needs to be tested...

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy that's a good point, and maybe my comment above is incorrect about the data resource lookup always happening during `plan` phase. I was under the impression that you couldn't put `depends_on` on a data resource, but if you can that  sounds like the solution.

Comment: Hi Thanks @Kombajnzbożowy  thanks for the comments, but I guess the problem is not with data resource, Data will always be referenced through parameters. I have edited my question above the top to show that.  Tha problem is the routetable, when subnet initially referenced, there was no routetable, so when we do plan, terraform will see that as null. but as part of the creation, it gets the routetable attached... I guess I could add some az cli at the end of pipeline to do that, but just curious, if terraform can natively do that

Comment: Hi @MarkB, I don't think we can do that. we can create a custom routetable, but this routetable needs to be controlled by AKS, incase we add/remove node pools

Comment: @MarkoE Mark, the AKS sits in its own module, and it generates the routetable ID. I'm writting a wraper  file to call AKS module and an application gateway module, inside this file, I'm hoping to pass in the routetable ID, so I can link the app gateway subnet to this routetable

Comment: I just posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026660/terraform-created-kubenet-aks-doesnt-link-routetable-to-app-gateway-subnet, I think in theory this routetable linking should be done automatically, I shouldn't need to write anycode myself, not sure if this is terraform provider problem

Comment: You've checked in the Azure web console and verified that the route table is not being created?

Comment: hi @MarkB the route table is created, but it's not associated to app gateway subnet